"don't we?" or "haven't we?" with "have got"
When I use "have got", what should I add to the end of the sentence for clarification purposes? "don't" or "haven't"?
What sentence is correct?
We've got a problem, don't we?
or
We've got a problem, haven't we?

I answered this question on EL&U some time ago: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/513066/havent-we-vs-dont-we/513082#513082

@Juhasz You don't address this specifically, do you? On that other site.

@Lambie Do you mean because that question asks about “we have” and this one about “we’ve got”?  I suppose “have” being an auxiliary verb here does make a difference.  I guess I didn’t answer so much as address this on the other site.

@Juhasz No, that's not it. In this specific case, it's about have got/have being two ways to say the same thing in the present tense with have and do as auxiliaries respectively.

People say all sorts of things, but some prefer a standard usage, which would be the following:

We've got a problem, haven't we? [auxiliary verb have]

or

We have a problem, don't we? [auxiliary verb, do]

Reminder: English has two present tenses for have in the sense of possess and some other uses like have got/have to do something: to have got and have. They mean the same thing.
You will hear people say:
We've got a problem, don't we?
But I prefer not to use that non-standard usage.
BBC English (it also applies to AmE)

'have' / 'have got'   When we are talking about possession,
relationships, illnesses and characteristics of people or things we
can use either have or have got. The have got forms are more common in
an informal style.
Have got has the same meaning as have and both are used as present
tenses. Note that have got is NOT the present perfect of get.
To make questions and negative sentences with have we normally use the
auxiliary verb do. To make questions and negative sentences with have
got we use the auxiliary verb have.
enter link description here


Omg, who would even think of downvoting this? I'm truly shocked.

I don't got no explanation!

This seems like the only possible correct answer to OP's question, so +1 from me :)

@MichaelHarvey I'm widya there, bro.

Following 'We have/we've [got] something,...' with 'don't we?' is pretty much exclusively US (and maybe Canadian?) English.

@MichaelHarvey No: If a Brit says, We have biscuits, don't we? or Or: We don't biscuits, do we? The auxiliary is DO. So, have with auxiliary do is not US or Canadian exclusively.
